# Combine two columns to one in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table with the columns:

```
`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`
```

With some rows like:

```
'1','bob','marley'
'2','mary','jane'
```

And i have a search query something like this (where 'bob marley' is my search term):

```
select * where
(`firstname` like 'bob marley%')
or
(`lastname` like 'bob marley%')
```

But this only gets a hit if i search for either 'bob' or 'marley', but not 'bob marley'
How can I concatenate two columns to match a search term?

edit:
The table will have hundreds of thousands of rows so performance is critical. is concat() efficient enough to work in an ajax search with delayed keystroke calls? or should i redesign my table or add a fulltext column for searching?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE 'bob marley%'
```

Answer (score 4):

This will destroy your query performance, but you can use [concat_ws](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to combine them with a space in between.

```
select *
from tbl
where concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname) like '%bob marley%'
```

Notice that I have **switched** your `right-sided-%` to `double-sided-%`.  This is necessary otherwise when searching using just marley, 'marley%' will not match.